# Clipping cursor to a panel

Tags: c#, cursor, cursor-position

Is there any way I can clip the cursor movement to panel area only? I am trying to get coordinates from a panel and after user clicks the mouse for the first time the cursor should move to panel and stay clipped there until the second mouse click. Thanks for answers.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); you have some problem X and thought “I know! I'll clip the cursor movement to panel area only”. For us to help we need to know X; why do you think “the cursor should move to panel and stay clipped there”?

Comment: So the user clicks on the button to place a point on a panel. So I want to move the cursor to the panel and stay there until the point has been selected by the second click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few assumptions I'm making here:

- You are using a windows form
- By clipping the cursor you mean moving the cursor

Here is my sample code to move the cursor from one panel to another:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Position = CenterPoint(panel2);
    }

    private void panel2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Position = CenterPoint(panel1);
    }

    private Point CenterPoint(Control control)
    {
        return new Point(
            Left + control.Left + control.Width / 2, 
            Top + control.Top + control.Height / 2);
    }

}
```

You can follow a similar logic on MouseMove event to limit movement

```
    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.X - panel1.Left < 20 && e.Y - panel1.Top < 20)
        {
            Cursor.Position = CenterPoint(panel1);
            Console.WriteLine($"{e.X} {e.Y}");
        }
    }
```

That will create a "No-Go" zone on the top left of the panel and if the cursor enters that area we send it back to the center

Comment: Yes I am using Windows form. Yeah you right, I meant moving the cursor only in panel area.

Comment: Then `Cursor.Position` is all you need! use it wisely or your application will feel weird

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. I moved the cursor to the upper left corner and used Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(panel1.Location, panel1.Size); to clip it there.